# Does connecting the gate of MOSFET to ground work?

Tags: mosfet

In a MOSFET, what happens if we connect the gate terminal to ground?

Does connecting gate to ground work?

Comment: It depends on the rest of the circuit, so.... schematic please.

Comment: How do you define "work"? If you mean does it turn on, then it depends on whether it is N-Channel, P-Channel, enhancement-mode, depletion mode, and most of all, it depends on what the source is doing.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of a MOSFET is mostly determined by the voltate difference between gate and source.

In the most common case, you have an N-channel enhancement MOSFET with the source connected to ground. So V<sub>GS</sub> would be zero, and the MOSFET would be off.

But it is also possible to have a P-channel MOSFET used as a high-side switch:
[image: P-channel MOSFET]
<sup>(source: http://www.learningelectronics.net/, [CC BY 1.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/1.0/))</sup>

If this gate is connected to ground, the MOSFET is always switched on.

So connecting the gate directly to ground usually does not make much sense; typically, you would use a variable gate voltage to control the MOSFET.

(There are some circuits, e.g., a MOSFET cascode, where you keep the gate voltage constant and vary the source voltage instead. But in any case, the gate-to-source voltage varies.)